# Хранение истории изменений записей в таблице

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеется таблица, в которой нужно вместо редактировании записи добавлять новую, а предыдущую запись помечать как невалидную. Возникает вопрос: что делать, если эта таблица связана с другой таблицей, ведь внешний ключ будет указывать на невалидную запись? Как изменять данные в другой таблице?

Comment: В некоторых СУБД есть специальные возможности для хранения исторических данных. Я не спец по мускулю, может кто-то точнее подскажет, но вот что быстро нашёл: [System-Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) и https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674043/5045688

Comment: Обсуждался похожий вопрос, и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1286205/218971 я описывал один из вариантов, как историю хранить. Там не затрагивался вопрос связей, но если коротко, то достаточно хранить ссылку на `id`, а не на `snapshot_id` (терминология из того ответа) .

Comment: *Как изменять данные в другой таблице?* Никак. У Вас разваливается атомарность. Впрочем, "вместо редактировании записи добавлять новую, а предыдущую запись помечать как невалидную" при наличии связанных записей по сути своей некорректно (особенно в случае, если по цепи внешних ключей обновлению должна подвергнуться хренова гора других таблиц). В рамках MySQL разумнее использовать триггер, который после обновления вставляет старую версию записи в архивную таблицу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Версионки в MySQL нет. Есть в MariaDB - впрочем, там всё равно надо сперва поплясать вокруг таблицы.

Comment: @Akina, а как быть при удалении записи?

Comment: Просто перемещаем в архив.

Comment: @Akina, а что делать с внешним ключом на основную запись в архивной таблице?

Comment: Так если запись удалена, какие на неё внешние ссылки?

Comment: @Akina, например, есть таблица A с первичным ключом A_id, которая имеет архивную таблицу A_history. В таблице A_history имется внешний ключ на A_id. Как произвести удаление записи в этом случае?

Comment: *В таблице A_history имется внешний ключ на A_id.* А нафига он нужен? Я бы ещё понял FK на себя, на предыдущую версию этой записи... Хотя именно в этом случае, если упёрлось, есть ON DELETE SET NULL.

Comment: @Akina, а как тогда знать с какой записью проводились операции, если у нас не будет ссылки?

Comment: На, изучай: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a385d510531f5289d6c31d5da26d6755)

Comment: @Akina, спасибо Вам большое за помощь!